# Private data types and member functions

Tags: c++, class

What does it actually mean when you declare a variable or a member function as private in a C++ class? Besides the obvious fact that, these are accessible only by the member functions, How are they mapped differently on memory, than their public counterparts?

Comment: I would be quite interested to know why you do require this information and how does it affect the code(compile/linking/execution) you write ??

Comment: I was thinking of ways to access the private data members using their memory addresses.

Comment: I was also afraid of this answer! if you need access to them either provide getters/ setters or why make them private? Perhapse protected is better!

Comment: @tsudot - Is that a hack for something sinister ? The variable is private for a reason.

Comment: No I was trying to see if there is a flaw in which private members and be accessed directly. I thought the compiler would put a flag on these which would make them inaccessible. Same way in which uids work on a linux kernel, where it is checked whether it matches with the current uid. (I just took a unix course, so I have a real vague idea of how it all works)

Comment: nope, accessability is only checked at compile time.

Comment: @DumbCoder I guess so, just trying to learn the core of compiler designs.

Comment: Besides the obvious fact that, these are accessible only by the member functions >> My dear friend, you are forgetting the all too important 'friends'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that they *were* only acessible from member functions, then code like this would break:

```
class Foo {
  int x; // this is private

public:
  int& X() { return x; } // this is public, but returns a reference to a private variable
};

Foo foo;
foo.X() = 42; // look, I can set the value of a private member without being inside a member function
```

In short, one of the most common way to define get/setters in C++ would break if there was some sort of magic enforcing that a private variable must only be accessed by member functions. That's obviously no good.

`public` and `private` are there to help the programmer structure his code, and nothing more. They offer absolutely no security, and no runtime protection against code accessing a "private" member. Variables are only private in the source code. In the compiled code, there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just assumed that declaring a variable private would make it secure.

Answer (score 3):

From standard docs, *9.2.12*,

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the **same access control** (clause 11) are allocated so that **later
>   members have higher addresses** within a class object. **The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified (11).** Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to
>   be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and
>   virtual base classes (10.1).

The standards has specs for the order of allocation of memory but there isn't much difference in the memory that is being allocated for a `public` data member and it's `private` counterpart..

Answer (score 1):

```
class priva
{
int x=10;
public:
int pub;
};
main()
{
priva a;
int *ptr;
ptr=&a.pub;
--ptr;//4 bite be4 there will be private data
cout<<"Private data having value of 10 is "<<endl;
cout<<*ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than accesability there is no difference!

Answer (score 0):

`public` and `private` are there only until compilation of the code. They don't have anything to do with the runtime or memory management.